# Swift Protocols with Typealises. Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: swift, protocols, factory, swift-protocols

I was thinking about the Validation checks in my app and I thought that calling ValidatorFactory on any model, that implements Validee, meaning saying which class is responsible for ValidatorCreation sounds sweet. But the code below doesn't work :(

Code:

```
struct Client: Validee {
    typealias ValidatorFactoryClass = ClientValidator
}

protocol Validee {
    associatedtype ValidatorFactoryClass: AbstractValidatorFactory
}

protocol Validator {
    func validate() throws -> Void
}

protocol AbstractValidatorFactory {
    associatedtype Model
    static func create(fromModel model: Model) -> Validator
}

struct ValidatorFactory {
    static func createValidator(fromModel model: Validee) -> Validator {
        return model.ValidatorFactoryClass.create(fromModel: model)
    }
}

struct ClientValidator : AbstractValidatorFactory {
    typealias Model = Client

    static func create(fromModel model: Model) -> Validator {
        return ClientDeliveryAddressValidator(withModel: model)
    }
}

struct ClientDeliveryAddressValidator: Validator {
    typealias Model = Client
    let client: Client

    init(withModel client: Client) {
        self.client = client
    }

    func validate() throws {

    }
}

let client = Client()
do {
    try ValidatorFactory.createValidator(fromModel: client).validate()
} catch {
    // error handling here
}
```

But even if I forget about the Validator Factory and try to run the following code it doesn't work:

```
client.ValidatorFactoryClass.create(fromModel: client)
```

Why ?

Comment: In what way does it “not work”?

Comment: @GaryMakin it just doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem you are having is due to compilation errors, your `ValidatorFactory` struct needs modifying.

You can’t use a protocol as a type directly. You use it as a constraint on a type. This means than rather than having `Validee` as a parameter type to `ValidatorFactory.createValidator`, it is a constraint on that type. This change would give you:

```
struct ValidatorFactory<T:Validee> {
    static func createValidator(fromModel model: T) -> Validator {
        return model.ValidatorFactoryClass.create(fromModel: model)
    }
}
```

This still has a problem because Swift cannot work out the relationship between the type `T` and the parameter type for the call to `create`. But the relationship exists in your code; you just need to make it explicit.

Changing `ValidatorFactory` to this compiles for me. I have not tried running the code, however.

```
struct ValidatorFactory<T:Validee> {
    static func createValidator(fromModel model: T) -> Validator {
        return T.ValidatorFactoryClass.create(fromModel: model as! T.ValidatorFactoryClass.Model)
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

Given that `Validee` already knows about the factory, it would be simpler to change the design so `Validee` knows about creating the Validator directly.

This would give you:

```
protocol Validee {
    static func create(fromModel model: Self) -> Validator
}

protocol Validator {
    func validate() throws -> Void
}

struct ValidatorFactory<T:Validee> {
    static func createValidator(fromModel model: T) -> Validator {
        return T.create(fromModel: model)
    }
}

struct Client: Validee {
    static func create(fromModel model: Client) -> Validator {
        return ClientDeliveryAddressValidator(withModel: model)
    }
}

struct ClientDeliveryAddressValidator: Validator {
    typealias Model = Client
    let client: Client

    init(withModel client: Client) {
        self.client = client
    }

    func validate() throws {

    }
}
```

Comment: But now Client is also a factory. And I wanted it to be a separate component

Comment: Or we can put it in an Extension

Comment: An extension makes sense. You could define your `Client` class elsewhere and the n change `struct Client: Validee` to `extension Client: Validee`. This would move all of the validation out of the real class.

Comment: Then, making it a static method, doesn't make much sense, or does it ? I just wanted to put the creation of the Validator-Object in another class, so that every component does it's thing, since then Client is also a ValidatorFactory (it can create instances of different classes, that create Validator-Object from the Client-Object, depending on the needs and situations. I guess it's more "swifty" to do it with extensions, but to me, it's kinda unusual